# A way to execute external script under rpmbuild or get RPM_BUILD_ROOT variable

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

In the process of building an RPM we are extracting some things from an archive in a directory A. We update the rpm.spec with the list of files from that archive in the %files section passing a file with -f with all that we got from the archive.

The next step at which we fail is the step where we need to copy the extracted files to the RPM_BUILD_ROOT folder A. Is there a way to get the RPM_BUILD_ROOT value to our script so that it will copy the files where needed?

Is there other way of adding the files from an archive into an RPM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. RPM_BUILD_ROOT is mktempd() (made easier). You cannot predict. For good reasons.

You want to add your files as SOURCE0, SOURCE1, SOURCE2.... and then you  can do:

```
%install
cp -a %{SOURCE0} %{SOURCE1} ... %{buildroot}/some/dir
```